# URL to do request on Laravel

Tags: android, rest, laravel

This may be a silly question, but I haven't find any way to solve it yet. My project mate wrote server side of our project using **Laravel**. My job is to develop Android App. I know how to send and receive JSON between Android and PHP. However, I don't know much about Laravel. So I don't know which URL should I use to send/receive JSON.

To which URL should I send my JSON to use the following post_list() method under the file my_application_name/application/controllers/menucategory.php ?

```
<?php

class MenuCategory_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public $restful = true;

    public function post_list() {
        $categories = MenuCategory::all();
        $cat = null;
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $cat[] = array(
                'id' => $category->id,
                'name' => $category->name
            );
        }
        return Response::json(array('categories' => $cat));
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Please share what's in your `routes.php` file... this is where [controller routing](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#controller-routing) takes place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the controller is restful, you just need to point to the name of the controller, and the name of the method (without the action)

e.g., in this case, you `post` to `menucategory/list` since it's the MenuCategory controller, and you `post` to `list`

More information on this can be seen in the laravel docs here: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers

Comment: routes.php doesn't have useful information in this sense. It has 2 line of codes related to "Application 404 & 500 Error Handlers"

Comment: In that case, perhaps try and `post` data to `menucategory/list`