# how to post data from android to laravel 3 controller

Tags: android, laravel, restful-url, laravel-routing, laravel-3

Hello guys i am using laravel 3, i want to make post request to laravel 3 controller.
here is coontroller users.php

```
      class Users_Controller extends Base_Controller
       {
           public $restful = true;

          public function post_signin()
          {
                 print("request success");
          }
        }
```

Here is routes.php

```
         Route::get('signin', array('as'=>'signin','uses'=>'users@signin'));
         Route::post('signin', array('uses'=>'users@signin'));
```

here is android post request

```
          httppost= new HttpPost("http://test.com/signin");
```

test.com is local domain i am using through host file. 
what url should i enter in android to make post request? so that it can go to users.php and execute post_signin method of that file.

i tried following

```
   1) httppost= new HttpPost("http://test.com/signin");  (as per my route of routes.php)

2)httppost= new               HttpPost("http://localhost/androidtest/application/controller/users.php");

   3) httppost= new HttpPost("http://test.com/users/signin");
   (as per this referance (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137851/url-to-do-request-on-laravel)
```

Comment: Do you get any response message from laravel? Can you post full android code of your request?

Comment: @user2432612  httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient(); String tmp=getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.site_url); httppost= new HttpPost(tmp+"/login.php");     response=httpclient.execute(httppost);   ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
   final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
   System.out.println("Response : " + response);

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment you are executing request two times but with different methods (execute). You just need one execute in order to make request to server. You are also using response variable as string and as HttpResponse object.

Please try to use code below to make your request, change url with your url

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

HttpResponse hResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
StatusLine sl = hResponse.getStatusLine();
int statusCode = sl.getStatusCode();

if ( statusCode == 200 ){
    HttpEntity hp = hResponse.getEntity();
    InputStream content = hp.getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        builder.append(line);
    }

    String responseBody = builder.toString();

    System.out.println("Response : " + responseBody); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. What should i write in my laravel controller?                                                                                         public function post_signin()
          {
                 print("request success");
          } or should i json parsing mathod to reply?

Comment: You can reply with response with couple of ways. One thing that i'am using when i process the request i create simple array with objects for example

`$res = array( "status" => $this->status,
    "response" => $this->response );

return $res`

than you can simply return that array and it will be converted to JSON string which you can parse inside application

You can checkout the doumentation for more info: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses